# my dvi-d port is not working for dual monitoring?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have two monitors. The first is an `LG Flatron w1946sn` and the second is an `LG Flatron ezt710sh` I am trying to connect them to my motherboard `J&W Z77A-prox` that supports dual monitoring. I am connecting the main display to the motherboard with a `VGA cable` and the second using a `VGA cable` and `DVI-D adapter`. It just detects the one that is connected to the `VGA` port, but it does not detect the one that is connected to the `DVI-D` port.
Can anyone help.

Comment: A legit DVI-VGA converter can only be plugged into DVI-A or DVI-I ports. Anything else if physically impossible unless excessive force is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into this same issue. A DVI-D is digital only port and even though you have a DVI-D adapter, an analog monitor will not work with the dvi "digital" port on your computer. I assume it's not a DVI-I port on your PC? If not you will have to buy an analog/digital converter to get this to work. Also important is to know a DVI "adapter" is not the same as a "converter". The fact they make so many types of DVI plugs makes this an easy mistake to make.

[image]

Comment: As an alternative if you happen to have a usb 3.0 port on your computer they sell vga-usb adapters on ebay for about $25. If you only have usb 2.0 this will still work but at a really bad resolution. I have found it sometimes cheaper though to just buy a graphics card that supports digital and analog outputs, than to buy an actual dvi-vga "converter", as these are generally pretty expensive.